# Generate a file From npm global module To the user's current path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, global, fs

I am creating a NPM module that will be installed globally on my computer, let's say it reside inside `<my-global-npm-module>` and inside of this folder I have my `index.html` file.

Goal: My goal is to copy the `index.html` file and paste into whatever/location folder my user is using, example: `my-app` folder.

I have the following `.js` code:

```
const fs = require('fs'); //File Server
const path = require('path');

let filename = 'index.html';
let src = path.join(__dirname, filename);
let destDir = path.join(__dirname, 'BlueFolder');

fs.access(destDir, (err) => {
  if(err) 
    fs.mkdirSync(destDir);  
  copyFile(src, path.join(destDir, filename));
});

function copyFile(src, dest) {

  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(src);
  readStream.once('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  readStream.once('end', () => {
    console.log('File has been copied.');
  });

  readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest));
}
```

If run this `.js` file it will copy and paste a new copy of the `index.html` file inside of `BlueFolder` which is also inside of my `<my-global-npm-module>` folder.  The correct should be inside of my user's folder, example: `my-app` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `process.cwd()`. This function returns the *current working directory* as a string.

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_cwd):

> The process.cwd() method returns the current working directory of the Node.js process.